# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cors

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myapi/api/rating. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8104' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I can't figure out why I can't make CORS requests. I've install the middleware here, added it to the global http kernel, but it still doesn't work. Tried to create a custom middleware given stackoverflow suggestions but that also did not work. Also tried adding a Route group. Lastly, I tried setting the response headers manually in the request action. I'm really stuck - help is appreciated!

See for code: https://gist.github.com/KerryRitter/0d7ababb7b9eb8d54f0ae55add9704a1

Comment: be simple, use this plugin: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: I did, that is the middleware I mentioned (forgot to say). I added to the kernel as seen in my gist

Comment: how about to keep it like: `'middleware' => [\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class]`

Comment: Alright, I removed the 'cors' registration and Cors class. removed the Route group. removed the request action headers. All i have is this for the Kernel
    protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class
    ];

Still no luck :(

Comment: Solved my problem on this: I didn't add "Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class" to the config/app.php providers array.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you are using `Laravel 5.5` & `Laravel 5.x` and facing same problem like `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`.  Just use following package and config your system.

Step 1:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

Step 2

You also need to add `Cors\ServiceProvider` to your `config/app.php` providers array:

```
FruitCake\Cors\CorsServiceProvider::class,
```

To allow `CORS` for all your routes, add the `HandleCors` middleware in the `$middleware` property of `app/Http/Kernel.php` class:

For global uses:

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

For middleware uses:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
   'web' => [
       // ...
   ],

   'api' => [
        // ...
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ],
];
```

Step 3

Once your installation completed run below command to publish the vendor files.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Fruitcake\Cors\ServiceProvider"
```

Hope this answer helps someone facing the same problem as myself.

Comment: in config/app.php we have to add this Fruitcake\Cors\CorsServiceProvider::class,

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Answer (score 24):

Laravel restricts the cross origin request due to security issues by default.
We need to create a Cors middleware to the accept the request from different origin.

Step 1 : Create Cors middleware.

```
php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

Step 2 : Add below lines in handle function before return.

```
//header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://localhost:4200');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, PUT');
```

Step 3 : Register the middileware in app/Http/Kernel.php file.

```
Add below line in $middleware array 

\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

Step 4 : Now we have to call the middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php file

```
Add below line in $routeMiddleware array 

'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the only thing that worked for me. I believe the other answers (or stuff I've seen online) don't mention the fact that we need to add the middleware to the `$middleware` array.

Comment: Thank You So Much Without using any package it did the work..

Comment: Using the `*` works rather than the host origin. Was missing the `Cors.php` `middleware in the array as well` Thank you

Comment: It the ONLY working method. A lot of wrong resources on web.

Comment: By any means is that bad for in production websites? I mean is it affecting security by any means?

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

The laravel-cors package allows you to send Cross-Origin Resource Sharing headers with Laravel middleware configuration.

Features

Handles CORS pre-flight OPTIONS requests
Adds CORS headers to your responses

Comment: Solved my problem on this: I didn't add "Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class" to the config/app.php providers array.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to localhost or *. Here's how I usually do it:
Create a simple middleware called `Cors`:

```
php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

Add the following code to `app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
```

You can replace the * with `localhost` or keep it as it is.

Next step is to load the `middleware`. Add the following line to the `$routeMiddleware` array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

```
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

And the final step is to use the middleware on the routes to which you want to set the access origin headers. Assuming you are talking about the new api routes in laravel 5.3, the place to do it is `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`, inside the `mapApiRoutes()` function (you can remove or comment the previous code of the function):

```
Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['api', 'cors'],
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
         //Add you routes here, for example:
         Route::apiResource('/posts','PostController');
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced this error in laravel 5.4 recently, i was sending ajax post request to my own website, and was still getting this same error, i faced this error due to two reasons to be precise,

`error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://[mydomain].com/quote/short. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://[mydomain].com' is therefore not allowed access.`

The reason for above error was that, i was posting request to http domain from https domain, so when i changed it to https, the error was resolved, then again i got the same error due to similar reason, which was the reason, this time, the domain had `www.` and the requested one did not, after i added `www.` to both, it worked like a charm.

And for cross origin requests, i used to following solution:

1. Create a middleware (cors in my case) having code below

   ```
   return $next($request)
       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
   ```
2. Insert middle-ware into routeMiddleware array in kernal.php

   `'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,`
3. Add middleware to the respected route

   `Route::get('myRoute', ['middleware' => 'cors' , 'uses'=> 'MyController@Action']`

Hope this answer helps someone facing the same problem as myself.

Answer (score 2):

ok, here is my try.
if i'm post to protected api using wrong token, passport return 401 with {"message":"Unauthenticated."}

but because there is no cors header exist on response, my vue app get CORS error and cannot handle the response code.

so at laravel 5.8 on http/kernel.php $middlewarePriority
add \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class before  \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class

here is my code:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:300,1',
        'Localization',
        'bindings',
        'cors'
    ],
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,

    // Add Localization MiddleWare
    'Localization' => \App\Http\Middleware\localization::class,
    'cors' => \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];

protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,

    //add to handle cors before authenticate
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,

    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
];
```

hope this help someone else

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had ran updates to move Laravel from v7.x to v9.x and resulted in localhost API access CORS errors.

If none of the above is working for you i tracked my issue down to the $headers variable within the TrustProxies Middleware.

The original value for this variable was Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;

After updating this to the below, it came back to life.

Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;

See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade and the Trusted Proxies section for reference.

What this all means for me is, read the whole of the upgrade docs, even if you dont think elements apply to your project...

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a composite project frontend Reactjs and Laravel backend when I encountered the *"preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin".*
**I resolved the problem by clearing the cache of the deployed Reactjs app on Heroku.**

[How do I clear the build cache?](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Just something I wanted to add something which I had to do in addition to the steps mentioned in the accepted answer.

I did encounter CORS error after couple of production deployments (Laravel version ^7.0 on Nginx) even after having setup HandleCors as mentioned here.
It started working after I ran `php artisan config:cache`, `composer install` and `composer dump-autoload`.

Hope this helps someone who is trying to debug what went wrong when you haven't updated any config files during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the error because some traits were missing in my models

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
```

So i added the header in the specific route, fixed theses errors, and then my headers went back to normal

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');