# Laravel API and Ionic 2 Client: CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: php, laravel, angular, ionic2, cors

I created an API with Laravel and I try to use it with an Ionic 2 project

I'm trying to make a GET request to my Laravel API.

When I make my `http` request to

```
auth/{prodiver}/callback/{userID}/{accessToken}
```

I got this error:

`Failed to load http://api.url.net/api/auth/facebook/callback/XXXX/MY_TOKEN: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8001' is therefore not allowed access.`

My route looks like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest', 'cors']], function() {
    Route::get('test', function () {
        return response()->json('{dummy.data}', 200);
    });

    Route::get('auth/{prodiver}/callback/{userID}/{accessToken}', 'SocialAuthController@callback')->middleware('cors')->name('social.auth'); // social auth
});
```

But when I try the same code, with the route `test`, it works and I got the data...

The "facebook connect" isn't the problem, the success callback is triggered.

Here is the `callback()` method

```
public function callback($provider, $userID, $accessToken)
{
    if ($provider == "facebook"){
        $user = $this->createOrGetUser($userID, $accessToken);
        auth()->login($user);
        return response()->json($user, 200);
    }
}
```

All other http requests works perfectly...

Here is the concerned `http` request (in Ionic project)

```
let headers = new Headers(); 
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
let url = this.baseApiUrl+'auth/facebook/callback/' + userID + '/' + accessToken; 
this.http
    .get(url, {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data)
        }, err => {
            this.onError(err);
        }
    );
```

I don't understand what's going on, anyone has a clue ? I'm totally tired of this error :/

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You've mentioned `cors` middleware. What package do you use, `barryvdh/laravel-cors`? Did you configure it properly?

Comment: Yes it is, I let the config to "*" everywhere, for developement...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header - Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565877/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-laravel-5-4)

Comment: You can try browser plugin Cross-Origin Resource Sharing(CORS). I was also facing this problem ionic +  laravel 5.2. It's work for me.

Comment: Yup, I can pass a CORS browser plugin, but isn't it a little bit stupid? It's for an Ionic app, and I can't ask the users to install it...

Answer (score 1):

First, why do you set `cors` middleware when defining the second route? It is already set for the whole group.

Second, `cors` returns a cors error in case you have some error in your code, that's its behaviour.

> When an error occurs, the middleware isn't run completely. So when
>   this happens, you won't see the actual result, but will get a CORS
>   error instead.

Try to debug your code to find a bug. Test returns data, it means that this is not the `cors` who gives the error, it is your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
I put CORS middleware on route and group, just to try, to be sure the middleware is "active"...
I'll check my code to find an error, thanks :)

Comment: You where right about the middleware! There was an error in my script... But I got an other problem with the "preflight request" now... :/