# How to fix CORS policy with cropperjs?

Tags: laravel, canvas, cropperjs

I want to crop image from external server and save it on mine. But I have many troubles with CORS policy, when trying to call

```
cropper.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob( (blob) => {
    console.log(blob);
    //and my ajax request
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header - Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565877/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-laravel-5-4)

Comment: Please, let me try to see. thanks

Comment: I am afraid, this does not change anything.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the No Access CORS response is coming from the external remote server, right? If so, it's the remote server that has an issue with the request headers. Perhaps you should consider using the Guzzle instead of CropperJS.

Comment: You need to configure your remote server so it sends the `access-control-allow-origin: *` and `access-control-allow-methods: GET, OPTIONS` headers.