# Vue Laravel Axios API Issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, cors

Im using vue axios call to access Laravel API's from localhost

Scenario 1: In axios call i got error

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed

then in Laravel API i put

```php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

this error goes and that axios call works

Scenario 2: For another axios call i got error

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

then in Laravel API i put

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

this error goes and that axios call works

In Laravel Kernel.php i have

```
protected $middleware = [
       \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];
```

Please check header slight differnces... why i need different header's for different calls? How can i resolve this?

Comment: Sounds like your CORS configuration is messed up. I recommend using the built-in middleware ~ `\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class`. There's no need to ever call `header()` with any `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers

Comment: in laravel kernel.php i laready have \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class

Comment: And what about your [configuration](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors#configuration)?

Comment: you mean config/cors.php ?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by following this solution: [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565877/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-laravel)

OR

Allow CORS through your `.htaccess` by adding the mentioned code

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
</IfModule>
```

Note:
This allow CORS from all hosts so better to allow trusted domain.